# How to check if a key-value pair exists in an array of dictionaries?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries where I need to check if a key-value pair exists and if not return a default value.

With the code below I can find a key-value pair if it exists.

```
let arrayOfDicts = [["Name": "JW", "amount": 50], ["Name": "Red Wine", "amount": 50], ["Name": "White Wine", "amount": 50], ["Name": "X", "amount": 50], ["Name": "JW", "amount": 50], ["Name": "Y", "amount": 50], ["Name": "Y", "amount": 50]]

let nameToFind = "Smirnoff"
var amount = ""

for i in 0..<arrayOfDicts.count{
    if arrayOfDicts[i]["ingredient"] as! String == nameToFind {
        amount = arrayOfDicts[i]["usedAmount"] as! String
    }
}
```

But I need to return a default value (let's say "0") if a key-pair value doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you want to compare both Name and amount?

Comment: no just name. Once I get the name right I get the respective amount.

Comment: I’ve added the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`filter(_:)`** on `arrayOfDicts` to filter all the elements with `"Name" == nameToFind`, i.e.

```
let arrayOfDicts = [["Name": "JW", "amount": 50], ["Name": "Red Wine", "amount": 50], ["Name": "White Wine", "amount": 50], ["Name": "X", "amount": 50], ["Name": "JW", "amount": 50], ["Name": "Y", "amount": 50], ["Name": "Y", "amount": 50]]
let nameToFind = "Smirnoff"
var amount = ""

let filteredDict = arrayOfDicts.filter {
    if let name = $0["Name"] as? String {
        return name == nameToFind
    }
    return false
}
```

To get the `amount`, use

```
amount = "\((filteredDict.first?["amount"] as? Int) ?? 0)"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to

```
struct Item {
    let name:String
    let amount:Double
}


let arrayOfDicts = [Item(name: "pppp", amount: 23)] 

func getValue(_ name:String) -> Double { 
    return arrayOfDicts.first(where: { $0.name == name })?.amount ?? 0 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sh_Khan. Works as intended.